# Resource dictionary not found in WPF prism user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following project structure:

[image]

When I tried to add Resoucse dictionary inside my user control FloorplanHierarchy I am getting file not found error:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source=".../UserControls/UserControlResources/LookUpEditTemplate.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

LookUpEditTemplate.xaml is inside the folder UserControlResources. Please help.

Comment: WPF surprises me again and again with funny syntax variations, but looking at 3 dots in that `Source` attribute makes me suspicious. You should check that relative path again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `UserControls` in the source because `UserControlResources` and `FloorplanHierarchy` both are in the same folder.

So changing this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source=".../UserControls/UserControlResources/LookUpEditTemplate.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

To this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../UserControlResources/LookUpEditTemplate.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Should works.

Comment: If I write like above it is looking for the file in view/usercontrolresources/lookupedittemplate.xaml. I don't think it is the correct location.

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty...Just test it. Based on your project structure this should works.

Comment: I tested it, found the path that I have written in my comment above in the exception. Can you please suggest something else?